# Call socket methods from another application? Asynchronous sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I've implemented a socket communication in java to communicate with an android device.
I need to receive the body of the messages from another application.
Is it possible to make an async socket that accpets message body from third-part software and then send the message?
I'm quite new to socket programming but i hope someone will help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TCProtocol uses two endpoints. 
Use another socket if you need to receive data from a second source.